# MongoDB How to get an item in a subdocument array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm very new to using Mongo and I have a collection that looks like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : "5e7a39ed-941a-4e07-af0b-df8764820206", 
    "title" : "Test Title Task", 
    "taskBody" : "This is a test task body", 
    "comments" : [
        {
            "_id" : "57b51a73-f585-4e80-ad51-107da707efd6", 
            "poster" : "Jack Black", 
            "comment" : "This is a comment"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "4ea314f3-3671-4568-b938-d8a1477ac681", 
            "poster" : "Joe Blow", 
            "comment" : "Another comment"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "c5f1a0e6-2fb9-429e-9931-8634f42fc143", 
            "poster" : "Mike Hall", 
            "comment" : " And yet Another comment"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm trying to get one of the comment elements by passing the ID like this:

```
getCommentById(id) {
        return tasks().then((taskCollection) => {
            return taskCollection.find({ "comments._id": id }).toArray().then((commentQuery) => {
                if (!commentQuery) throw "Comment not found";
                return commentQuery;
            });
        });
    }
```

However, it seems to be returning everything in the comments collection and not just one comment that I'm passing in the id for.  How can I get it to return just the comment that I'm passing the id for?

This is what the debug window shows me

```
Array(1) [Object]
Object {_id: "5e7a39ed-941a-4e07-af0b-df8764820206", title: "Test Title Task", taskBody: "This is a test task body", …}

Array(3) [Object, Object, Object, …]
0: Object {_id: "57b51a73-f585-4e80-ad51-107da707efd6", poster: "Jack Black", comment: "Comment text 2"}

1: Object {_id: "4ea314f3-3671-4568-b938-d8a1477ac681", poster: "Joe Blow", comment: "Another comment"}

2: Object {_id: "c5f1a0e6-2fb9-429e-9931-8634f42fc143", poster: "Joe Blow", comment: "Another comment"}
```

What I'm expecting to get returned is just:

```
{
    "_id" : "57b51a73-f585-4e80-ad51-107da707efd6", 
    "poster" : "Jack Black", 
    "comment" : "This is a comment"
}
```

Assuming "57b51a73-f585-4e80-ad51-107da707efd6" is the passed in ID.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are querying sub array correctly. But your assumption is wrong. While you are querying with a specific sub document of an array field, a find query will still return a list of actual documents. You execute find on collection not just on an array field of a single document.

What you can do with mongoDB is this: you can exclude or include fields for your select queries. So you does not read unnecessary fields from mongoDB and it improves performance. You can learn more about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

So for your question; while you just want to read a sub document in an array field, you have to use `$` operator too. You can find more information [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

Your query should look like this:

```
db.collection.find({ "_id": "some id", "comments._id": "some id"}, {"comments.$": 1, "_id": 0})
```

But again remember: This query will still return a list(or one collection if you use `findOne`) of your **actual document**, not a list of **comment**. Returned json will look like this:

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "_id" : "57b51a73-f585-4e80-ad51-107da707efd6", 
      "poster" : "Jack Black", 
      "comment" : "This is a comment"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** If you really want just a comment with structure in your question. You can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and play the structure of json before return.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work!  I got back [{"comments":[{"_id":"c993dfa7-d798-48ee-9e3f-bbbec8fcb564","poster":"John Doe","comment":"Test Comment by John Doe"}]}]  I also tried the other suggestion taskCollection.find({ "comments": {$elemMatch: { _id: 'your value here '}}})   and that was returning the main task document and still every single comment

Answer (score 0):

```
taskCollection.find({ "comments": {$elemMatch: { _id: 'your value here '}}})
```

This should work for you.

Comment: already he is using `DOT` operation to retrieve from array, that should work , the  query what he is posted is correct. ALso `elemMatch` will suit for multiple key conditions.